# Create nodes and relations conditionally when loading nodes from csv in Neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have a data set in csv format. One of the fields is a type, like an enumeration. Based on this type I need to create different types nodes and relations when loading the data using csv load. You could call a row in the csv for a super type having an attribute defining its subtype.

I'm not really able to figure out how this can be done in cypher. Is my only option to split the one csv file into a csv file per type and run different cyphers ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [document on conditional statements](http://java.dzone.com/articles/neo4j-load-csv-handling-empty) helps.

Here is a simple example for loading based on a column value:

Data:
a,b
Ford,car
Chevy,truck
Mazda,car
GMC,truck
F150,truck

Cypher code:

```
load csv with headers from "file:/testfile.csv" as row
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN trim(row.b) = "truck" THEN [1] ELSE [] END | MERGE (p:Truck {vehicleType: row.a}))
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN trim(row.b) = "car" THEN [1] ELSE [] END | MERGE (p:Car {vehicleType: row.a}))
```

When you are done, you will have nodes created of different types.

Comment: Very useful trick! It's a pity Cypher doesn't support this directly, or does it?.

Comment: Ugliest hack to work with COMMERCIAL software that I have seen in a while.  Where is the elegant solution from the Neo4j people?