# Noe4j Cypher - conditional statements

Tags: neo4j, cypher

To express conditions in cypher, I am still using the following trick :

```
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN //Put conditions here// THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
//Put instruction here// )
```

I've been using this for quite a while. Is there a better solution now ? Will there be in the next stable version ?

Edit : 
I am refering to cases where the MATCH/WHERE pattern can't be used.
For exemple : 
[Create nodes and relations conditionally when loading nodes from csv in Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557457/create-nodes-and-relations-conditionally-when-loading-nodes-from-csv-in-neo4j/25558022#25558022)

or https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=FOREACH%28ignoreMe+IN+CASE+WHEN

Comment: I usually make conditions based on what data is in the actual graph; e.g. MATCH (a) where a.someCondition = 1 WITH a (do something else)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much better you'd consider this, but another way to approach the `LOAD CSV` would be to do:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from "file:/testfile.csv" as row
WHERE trim(row.b) = 'truck'
MERGE (p:Truck {vehicleType: row.a}));

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from "file:/testfile.csv" as row
WHERE trim(row.b) = 'car'
MERGE (p:Car {vehicleType: row.a}));
```

Parsing a CSV file doesn't take much time (at least relatively to the queries), so it shouldn't be too big of a deal to do it twice.

Another option would be to use the `neo4j-import` command ( http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html ).  You might need to modify your CSV files, but it imports much faster.  Also this wouldn't work for incremental updates to your database.  `neo4j-import` creates a new database from scratch each time you run it (which is part of why it can be so fast)

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. Please note that I am not asking about CSV import, but specificaly about expressing a condition in Cypher in the few cases where it gets tricky